# Regular Expression for attribute/value not working in Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to avoid texts like this one:  height="49" with a regular expression.

I tried `.replaceAll("\s*="*"","");`

(replaceAll is used as a method in a java class), but eclipse don't allowed me to do that.
Any other suggestion??

Comment: What is the pattern that you would like to match?

Comment: What is the reasoning to use \s* here? I'm not sure if that code actually compiles in the first place. Here's some reference: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: \s matches whitespaces, maybe you mean \w which matches word characters (alphanumerical and _)

Comment: `height="49"`? Sounds like parsing HTML with regex. You may want to discuss/rethink this approach... Also, in the future questions/problems you should prefer posting the exact and entire error message instead of saying "it does not allow me to do that".

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `\` in Java string literal to `\\`, and you need to escape the `"` to `\"`.

```
.replaceAll("\\s*=\".*?\"","")
```

#### See also

- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

> The character and string escape sequences allow for the representation of some nongraphic characters as well as the single quote, double quote, and backslash characters in character literals (§3.10.4) and string literals (§3.10.5).
>
> ```
> EscapeSequence:
>         \ b                     /* \u0008: backspace BS                   */
>         \ t                     /* \u0009: horizontal tab HT              */
>         \ n                     /* \u000a: linefeed LF                    */
>         \ f                     /* \u000c: form feed FF                   */
>         \ r                     /* \u000d: carriage return CR             */
>         \ "                     /* \u0022: double quote "                 */
>         \ '                     /* \u0027: single quote '                 */
>         \ \                     /* \u005c: backslash \                    */
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash and the double quotes inside the string. Also you probably meant to write `.*` everywhere you wrote `*` (though that would likely not give you the results you want either, so you should use something more specific than `.`).

Answer (score 0):

This needs a good deal more clarification, but your specific example can be found using

```
String.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+=\"\d+\"","")
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Check the `java` tag (and other answers).